# I want to score players based on their positions in a quiz game

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I am building a multiplayer quiz game, The code below gives one point on the correct answer and minus one on the wrong.
But I want it like this: if a player answer first it gets 2 points, 2nd player gets 1 point, and the wrong answer 0 points for the same question.

```js
function enableAnswering() {
                // Enable clicking of answers buttons
                document.querySelectorAll("#answers .optionblock").forEach((answer) => {
                    answer.onclick = (e) => {
                        const answerButton = answer;
                        const playerAnswer = answer.dataset.answer;
                        const playerNumber = Number(answerButton.dataset.player);
                        const correctAnswer = options[thiskey];
                        
                        if (playerAnswer.toLowerCase() == correctAnswer.toLowerCase()) {
                            answerButton.classList.add("correctAnswer");
                            scores[playerNumber] += 2;
                            
                            var plusAudio = new Audio("../audio/correct.mp3");
                            plusAudio.play();
                                clearQuestionTimerManually();
                                setTimeout(() => {
                                loadNextQuestionInHTML();
                            }, 2000);
                        }
                        else {
                            answerButton.classList.add("wrongAnswer");
                            scores[playerNumber]--;
                            // answerButton.attr('disable','disable');
                            var minusAudio = new Audio("../audio/Wrong.mp3");
                            minusAudio.play();
                        }
                        finishGameAndShowResults();
                        answer.onclick = () => {};
                    };
                });
            }
```

Comment: What is your question? You only provided a goal but no mention of problems you are having achieving that goal. See [ask]

Comment: I tried few things but it messed the whole thing so I uploaded the working version of the code. Kindly provide any hint to this goal. Thanks you